# Slow typing in Angular forms and ngbmodal

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I have changed my components change detection strategy to onPush. Still, the typing is slow in forms and ngbmodal popup

Comment: Your question is so anonymous. You have to add more details so that others can know your problem clearly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your problem? Please add example code. Without that, no user can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

we are not able to understand your problem clearly with provided information. So, we request you share the code snippet, screen shot, stackblitz sample for better understanding.